# How to prevent from a new pages after titles at KOMA-script book?

Tags: lyx, koma-script, scrbook

How do I prevent from new page after the title  at `KOMA-script book`?
After the title it's make a new page.

Can I prevent from it?

(I'm using LyX)

Thank you!

:: Edit ::
Here is MWE:

```
% Preview source code

%% LyX 2.3.2-2 created this file.  For more info, see http://www.lyx.org/.
%% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,english,hebrew,titlepage=false,numbers=noenddot]{scrbook}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\setlength{\parindent}{0bp}

\makeatletter

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% LyX specific LaTeX commands.
\pdfpageheight\paperheight
\pdfpagewidth\paperwidth


\@ifundefined{date}{}{\date{}}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Script=Hebrew]{David CLM}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfonttt[Script=Hebrew]{Miriam Mono CLM}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfontsf[Script=Hebrew]{Simple CLM}
\AtBeginDocument{
\renewcommand\footnoterule{%
  \kern -3pt
  \hbox to \textwidth{\hfill\vrule height 0.4pt width .4\textwidth}
  \kern 2.6pt
}}
\renewcommand{\labelenumii}{\labelenumi\arabic{enumii}.}
\addtokomafont{disposition}{\rmfamily}
\KOMAoptions{titlepage=false}

\makeatother

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{hebrew}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\begin{document}
\title{\begin{english}[variant=american]%
ABC
\end{english}}%
\maketitle

\chapter{ABC}

abc
\end{document}
```

Comment: If you want an in-page title (aka title head) use option `titlepage=false` as documented in the KOMA-Script manual. But for book, I would not recommend to do so.

Comment: I would not recommend to use `scrbook` for documents, that should not start a new page for each *chapter*. Use `scrartcl` instead and sections instead of chapters.

Comment: Which benefits do you like to use, that are not provided by `scrartcl`?

Comment: @Schweinebacke - the chapters, and all the levels the book suggesting me :-)

Comment: @Schweinebacke, you right and I edited my question...

Comment: No, you don't want to use chapters. Because chapters start a new page. You don't want them to make a new page, so you don't want chapters. If you need more section levels than section, subsection, subsubsection, paragraph and subparagraph `scrartcl` also supports adding additional level. You could even add a level above `section` and call it `chapter`.

Comment: @Schweinebacke, you right! Thank you! (I'll ask it at other question)...

Comment: Argh! Maybe the LyX authors should read (sorry, German page, but the image of four paragraphs, that demonstrates why it is bad practice, is international): »[Was ist eigentlich so schlimm daran, \parindent auf Null zu setzen?](https://komascript.de/faq_parindent)«.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the KOMA-Script manual:

[image: screenshot from the KOMA-Script manual]

So you just need to set option `titlepage=false` to produce a in-page title with `scrbook`, e.g.:

```
\documentclass[titlepage=false]{scrbook}
\begin{document}
\title{Title}
\author{Schweinebacke}
\maketitle
And here comes additional text.
\end{document}
```

[image: in-page title with scrbook]

As also explained in the KOMA-Script manual, you can set the option not only with `\documentclass` but also using `\KOMAoptions`:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\KOMAoptions{titlepage=false}
\begin{document}
\title{Title}
\author{Schweinebacke}
\maketitle
And here comes additional text.
\end{document}
```

Same result.

But note: This does not prevent, e.g., `\chapter` from starting a new page, if it follows `\maketitle`. And note, `\tableofcontents` etc. also use `\chapter` (or `\chapter*` or `\addchap`).

Private note: In my opinion it does not make any sense to use `scrbook` with an in-page title. Books should always use title pages. So I'm even astonished that book classes provide in-page titles.

Comment: I need to put it at "class options"? Thank you!

Comment: Do you know how to do it at LyX? At class options it's doesn't work.... :-(

Comment: Maybe LyX shares my opinion. Or maybe there is an option `titlepage` somewhere in the document settings. I never use LyX, sorry. But maybe `\KOMAoptions` does work.

Comment: This is what I tried but it's don't work :-(

Comment: `\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,english,hebrew,titlepage=false,numbers=noenddot]{scrbook}` There is a problem with this line maybe??

Comment: @heblyx This line is ok. Have a look at the LaTeX code that LyX produces. BTW: `\KOMAoptions` can be used even *after* `\begin{document}`. This would not be good practice, but the code of LyX often is not best practice too. BTW: Such problems are one reason, why you always should add a MWE to your question.

Comment: I add one! Can you tell me why it's not working for me?? Thank you!

Comment: @heblyx I've already explained this from the very first version of my answer. Please see the first note in my answer starting with: "But note".

Comment: I saw it. But how it's relevant to my MWE?

Comment: @heblyx It's about `\chapter` following `\maketitle` and if you have a look into your example you will find `\chapter` immediately following to `\maketitle`. So not the `\maketitle` does start a new page after the title, but `\chapter` still starts a new page before the title heading. This is exactly the thing I've explained!

Comment: You right! Now it's working!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90933/discussion-between-heblyx-and-schweinebacke).