# How to prevent from chapters and parts from start at a new page at scrbook?

Tags: lyx, koma-script, hebrew, scrbook

Here - [How to prevent from a new pages after titles at KOMA-script book?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/479074/how-to-prevent-from-a-new-pages-after-titles-at-koma-script-book/479078?noredirect=1#comment1210209_479078) - you were asked my why I want to prevent from new pages at `scrbook` instead of using the `strartcl`.

So one of the answers is the RTL benefits:
Here is a MWE -

```
% Preview source code

%% LyX 2.3.2-2 created this file.  For more info, see http://www.lyx.org/.
%% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,english,hebrew,titlepage=false,numbers=noenddot]{scrbook}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\setlength{\parindent}{0bp}

\makeatletter

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% LyX specific LaTeX commands.
\pdfpageheight\paperheight
\pdfpagewidth\paperwidth


\@ifundefined{date}{}{\date{}}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Script=Hebrew]{David CLM}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfonttt[Script=Hebrew]{Miriam Mono CLM}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfontsf[Script=Hebrew]{Simple CLM}
\AtBeginDocument{
\renewcommand\footnoterule{%
  \kern -3pt
  \hbox to \textwidth{\hfill\vrule height 0.4pt width .4\textwidth}
  \kern 2.6pt
}}
\renewcommand{\labelenumii}{\labelenumi\arabic{enumii}.}
\addtokomafont{disposition}{\rmfamily}
\KOMAoptions{titlepage=false}

\makeatother

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{hebrew}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\begin{document}
\title{\begin{english}[variant=american]%
ABC
\end{english}}%
\maketitle

\part{ABC}

\chapter{cxcx \texthebrew{שלום}}

\chapter{dsds}
\end{document}
```

The RTL works here perfect while at the `scrartcl` it's make problems...
[image]
[image]

This is how it should look like, but at the `scrartcl` it will be on the left side... :( [and at `scrbook` it's on the right side - how it shuold be...]

Can yoiu help me please and tell me how do I prevent from new pages after Parts and Chapters?

Thank you!!

Comment: Wouldn't asking how to do it with scrartcl, or rather why it doesn't work out of the box, be the smartest question?

Comment: I tried do to it and I didn't success... But, it's impossible to prevent an new page after parts and chapters? If it possible it will help me a lot... :-)

Comment: You should show the problematic code with scrartcl. Whatever breaks there will break with scrbook probably too. You are not gaining anything by trying to avoid to solve this problem.

Comment: Broadly speaking, you want to break and remove the features that book adds over article.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer - Here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/479111/how-to-make-parts-and-sections-at-the-right-side-of-the-document

Comment: @Johannes_B, I'm not say that I'm breaking it, I just wonder how to do it :)

Comment: You could do `\RedeclareSectionCommand[style=section]{chapter}` (maybe you would need to add additional options) to make `\chapter` a section. But this would not really help you, because this is a XY problem. You should try to generate correct code to get correct results not to bend LaTeX and KOMA-Script until it generates the expected result from the wrong code.

Comment: BTW: For XY problem see: [What does “XY Problem” mean?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2449/9057)

Comment: @Schweinebacke, thank you! I new at KOMA-Script...