# How to make parts and sections at the right side of the document?

Tags: koma-script, hebrew, right-to-left

I'm writing a document at Hebrew at `scrartcl` class (KOMA-script) and the parts and the sections are at the left side when I writing at English:
[image]

How can I move it to the right? (like at `scrbook` - there it's perfect!)

MWE:

```
    % Preview source code

    %% LyX 2.3.2-2 created this file.  For more info, see http://www.lyx.org/.
    %% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
    \documentclass[a4paper,english,hebrew,numbers=noenddot]{scrartcl}
    \usepackage{fontspec}
    \setlength{\parindent}{0bp}

    \makeatletter

    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% LyX specific LaTeX commands.
    \pdfpageheight\paperheight
    \pdfpagewidth\paperwidth


    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
    \newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Script=Hebrew]{David CLM}
    \newfontfamily\hebrewfonttt[Script=Hebrew]{Miriam Mono CLM}
    \newfontfamily\hebrewfontsf[Script=Hebrew]{Simple CLM}
    \AtBeginDocument{
    \renewcommand\footnoterule{%
      \kern -3pt
      \hbox to \textwidth{\hfill\vrule height 0.4pt width .4\textwidth}
      \kern 2.6pt
    }}
    \renewcommand{\labelenumii}{\labelenumi\arabic{enumii}.}
    \addtokomafont{disposition}{\rmfamily}

    \makeatother

    \usepackage{polyglossia}
    \setdefaultlanguage{hebrew}
    \setotherlanguage{english}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{english}[variant=american]%

    \part{abc}

    \section{abc \texthebrew{גדה}}
    \end{english}%

    \end{

document}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

In scrbook the same would happen too. You are putting an english environment around your \section and this moves it to the left as wanted with this language.

With

```
  \begin{document}


    \part{abc}

    \section{abc \texthebrew{גדה}}
    %

    \end{document}
```

It works as expected (I had to change the fonts):

[image]

Comment: I'm using LyX, can you explain me how to do it on LyX?

Comment: No, I'm not using lyx and I have no idea when it inserts such code.

Comment: So you can help here? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/479097/how-to-prevent-from-chapters-and-parts-from-start-at-a-new-page-at-scrbook?noredirect=1&lq=1 (this is other way to do it...)

Comment: If you don't know how to prevent lyx to switch to english, it can happen at any time in your document also with scrbook as class.  Find out how to control the language environments in lyx or don't use lyx.

Comment: I know how to change the language at LyX to English but it's doesn't help. At `scrbook` it's work perfect!! I just need to know how to prevent from making a new pages at parts and chapters... :-(

Comment: But you seem not to know how to remove the wrong english environment. Sorry but your problem is not with KOMA or Latex, you can't handle lyx correctly. So learn it.

Comment: You right - the problem is at LyX.... I tried to do anything with the software but maybe its something that the software don't allow me to do... :)  revent from making a new pages at parts and chapters it's one way to "solve" it....

Comment: @heblyx No it is not. You could learn LaTeX and use a LaTeX editor. You could use [ERT](https://wiki.lyx.org/FAQ/ERT) to add the correct code on your own. You could [ask other LyX users](https://www.lyx.org/MailingLists#toc10) how you can handle LyX to get the expected result, you could try to switch back to Hebrew *before* adding a new section or to avoid switching to English before the section but only locally for one word *inside* the heading, if you try to put one English word into a Hebrew section heading.

Comment: @Schweinebacke, you right and thank you for your answer... I'll try to ask the LyX community (I'm trying to avoid ERT if possible), and about "switch back to Hebrew before adding a new section or to avoid switching to English before the section but only locally for one word inside the heading" - I tried it with no success :(

Answer (score 1):

The result of KOMA-Script is absolutely correct and expected. I've added some comments to explain how it works:

```
% Most of the code has been produces using LyX 2.3.2-2 which produces
% very ugly code, that often is not recommended by the KOMA-Script author,
% typographers or LaTeX experts.
\documentclass[a4paper,english,hebrew,numbers=noenddot]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setlength{\parindent}{0bp}% Nonsense: see https://komascript.de/faq_parindent

\makeatletter% Not needed!

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% LyX specific LaTeX commands.
\pdfpageheight\paperheight % Nonsense: Does fail with LuaTeX!
\pdfpagewidth\paperwidth   % Nonsense: Does fail with LuaTeX!


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Script=Hebrew]{David CLM}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfonttt[Script=Hebrew]{Miriam Mono CLM}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfontsf[Script=Hebrew]{Simple CLM}
\AtBeginDocument{
\renewcommand\footnoterule{% Nonsense: Does break KOMA-Script!
  \kern -3pt
  \hbox to \textwidth{\hfill\vrule height 0.4pt width .4\textwidth}
  \kern 2.6pt
}}
\renewcommand{\labelenumii}{\labelenumi\arabic{enumii}.}
\addtokomafont{disposition}{\rmfamily}

\makeatother

\usepackage{polyglossia}% Polyglossia has known bugs!
\setdefaultlanguage{hebrew}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\begin{document}
\begin{english}[variant=american]% Here you switch to English, so not
                                 % longer RTL but LTR. Default for parts
                                 % and sections in LTR is \raggedright =
                                 % left aligned. But you can change is
                                 % using:
  \renewcommand*{\raggedpart}{\raggedleft}%
  \renewcommand*{\raggedsection}{\raggedleft}%
  \part{abc}

  \section{abc \texthebrew{גדה}}
\end{english}%

% Now, we are Hebrew again, so we are in RTL. Default for parts and
% sections is \raggedright that is right aligned in RTL:

\part{\textenglish{abc}}
\section{\textenglish{abc} גדה}

\end{document}
```

[image: result]

It it neither the fault of KOMA-Script nor of LaTeX if a user or LyX produces strange code.

BTW: It is not true, that `scrbook` does a different alignment of the headings:

```
% Most of the code has been produces using LyX 2.3.2-2 which produces
% very ugly code, that often is not recommended by the KOMA-Script author,
% typographers or LaTeX experts.
\documentclass[a4paper,english,hebrew,numbers=noenddot,oneside]{scrbook}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setlength{\parindent}{0bp}% Nonsense: see https://komascript.de/faq_parindent

\makeatletter% Not needed!

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% LyX specific LaTeX commands.
\pdfpageheight\paperheight % Nonsense: Does fail with LuaTeX!
\pdfpagewidth\paperwidth   % Nonsense: Does fail with LuaTeX!


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Script=Hebrew]{David CLM}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfonttt[Script=Hebrew]{Miriam Mono CLM}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfontsf[Script=Hebrew]{Simple CLM}
\AtBeginDocument{
\renewcommand\footnoterule{% Nonsense: Does break KOMA-Script!
  \kern -3pt
  \hbox to \textwidth{\hfill\vrule height 0.4pt width .4\textwidth}
  \kern 2.6pt
}}
\renewcommand{\labelenumii}{\labelenumi\arabic{enumii}.}
\addtokomafont{disposition}{\rmfamily}

\makeatother

\usepackage{polyglossia}% Polyglossia has known bugs!
\setdefaultlanguage{hebrew}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\begin{document}
\begin{english}[variant=american]% Here you switch to English, so not
                                 % longer RTL but LTR. Default for chapters
                                 % and sections in LTR is \raggedright =
                                 % left aligned. But you can change is
                                 % using:
  \chapter{abc}

  \section{abc \texthebrew{גדה}}
\end{english}%

\end{document}
```

(Here I've only changed `scrartcl` into `scrbook` and added option `oneside` and changed `\part` into `\chapter`.)

So there is no difference whether you use `scrbook` or `scrartcl`.

[image: with scrbook]

Comment: You right at your words, but I'm using LyX... :-) BTW, the first section it's doesn't RTL... `scrbook` display it at the correct way, this is why I asked this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/479097/how-to-prevent-from-chapters-and-parts-from-start-at-a-new-page-at-scrbook?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @heblyx You are wrong. `scrbook` displays it the same. I've added an example to my answer. So there is another difference in your `scrbook` document. And using LyX does not prevent users from making strange things. If you mix LTR and RTL you have to be careful *when* or *where* you do the switching of the languages.

Comment: So why for my it's working perfect at `scrbook`? https://i.stack.imgur.com/8AzFA.png

Comment: and at `scrartcl` it's appear wrong?

Comment: @heblyx See my previous comment. Maybe because you've done something different that produces some different LaTeX code. E.g. switching back to Hebrew *before* the heading has another result than switching back *inside* the heading. I've shown this with the second `\part` and `\section` in my first example.